# How to get an object of the property that it belongs to?

Tags: c#, loops, object, properties, instance

```
            Type type = entity.GetType();                
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (var p in properties)
            {

                if(p.Name == "State")
                {                        
                    context.Entry(INSTANCE_TO_WHICH_THE_PROPERTY_p_BELONGS_TO).State = FunctionThatWillSetTheState(p.State)
                }
            }
```

The method with generic signature receives an instance of a class "entity"

```
public static void EntityAction<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
        where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState
```

then loops through the properties in that instance
Ho do i get object/instance of a class that the property "p" belongs to?

because i need to tell this function

```
context.Entry(INSTANCE_TO_WHICH_THE_PROPERTY_p_BELONGS_TO).State = FunctionThatWillSetTheState(p.State)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have the instance: `entity` - or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: Please tag your questions with the programming language you are using.

Comment: Entity is a generic instance of the class that is being passed and i need to know what type of instance (entity) was passed here is the methot that receives "entity" :


      public static void EntityAction<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
            where TEntity : class, IObjectWithState

Comment: If you have TEntity type parameter then you can simply say typeof(TEntity).GetProperties(...) instead of entity.GetType() - probably slight advantages to this eg. better performance & handling of entity = null

Comment: It will work if that entity does not have children or parent. Ex: Class Entity {public string Name {get; set;} public Address Address {get; set;}} Where class "Entity" is a child and "Address" is a parent. The idea of the method that I'm trying to accomplish is to get an "Entity" and loop through its properties including any children or parents that the "Entity" has. As loop is going through all the properties, parents and children it will be setting different type of states to "Entity" and its children and parent.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the type of the class the PropertyInfo was declared on:

```
var t = property.DeclaringType;
```

If you already have the instance, then you can get the value of that property for that particular instance>

```
var v = property.Getvalue(myInstance, null);
```

But if you don't already have the instance (eg. "entity" in your example) then it is impossible to get an instance from the Type or PropertyInfo. Reflection deals only with types & definitions, not any particular instance.

Comment: Ex: Class Entity {public string Name {get; set;} public Address Address {get; set;} List<Person> People {get; set;}} Where class "Entity" has a parent "Address" and children "People". The idea of the method that I'm trying to accomplish is to get an "Entity" and loop through its properties including any children or parents that the "Entity" has. As loop will be going through all the properties, parents and children it will be setting different type of states to "Entity" and its children and parent.